# htaccess rules on apache2

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I need a ligth on an .htaccess file that i dont understand.
I am using linux with apache2 and cant figure what is wrong.
I had this working but changed something and not working anymore.
Here is the .htaccess. I want to say i just start to fix bugs in this legacy software. I am more a Js than php developer.

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge" "expr=%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m#text/html#i"
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Im using a virtual host.
I can see myhost.com but soon a click a link, i get a 404 not found error
i know is something with apache or php , because this code is working in another server. I supose. They say so.
Please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i had a typo on sites available conf file